# HTML Block Anchor element only half clickable in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I ran into a strange CSS problem in Chrome.
I made a pen as example:

http://codepen.io/bbredewold/pen/hprDA

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 90px;
    height: 94px;
    border: 4px solid white;
}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 86px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

    .flip .card .face {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .flip .card .back a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
    }
```

I made a few div's with inside hyperlinks. I've set the displaymode to Block, so the link should stretch to the whole area.

It doesn't. It only stretches the bottom half of the div. In Firefox it works fine. Only Chrome seems to have this problem.
Couldn't find any bug that supports my problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome you say? That's easy, if it doesn't go one way, try it the other way. Try changing

```
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
```

To

```
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatex(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotatex(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotatex(180deg);
    transform: rotatex(180deg);
}
```

Comment: It's really about the whole square that should be clickable. Your answer answers no problem... ;)

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Cuz it does work for me, initially only bottom half gets anchor to get focused. After this change whole square gives anchor focus.

Comment: I just tested this with your pen in chrome on windows 8, and it did the trick.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, it works indeed! It's strange though... Thanks a lot!